# Ant: how to remove the first and last lines of files in a folder and concatenate them all together?

Tags: ant

I wrote sth. like this:

```
<project>
       <concat destfile="myDir/concat_file.txt" append="true">
             <fileset dir="myDir">
                    <include name="**/*.txt" />
                    <exclude name="**/concat_file.txt” />
             </fileset>
             <filterchain>
                    <headfilter lines="-1" skip="1" />
                    <tailfilter lines="-1" skip="1" />
             </filterchain>
       </concat>
</project>
```

I can concatenate all the files in the folder, but the filterchain part works only for the first file. How can I make it iteratively for all the files in the folder and then do the concatenation?